# How do I run load tests with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

Seems like most of the information on the web is for MS Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition and the ones that do mention VS2012 don't go into detail on how to start a load test.

When I want to create a new project or add a new project and I go to Test, the only two options are: Unit Test Project and Coded UI Test Project. I don't see a load test option?

If anyone can navigate me through the steps on how to create a load test (generate X amount of users to load my ASP.NET MVC web app), that would be great.

Comment: You need VS2012 Ultimate Edition to be able to run load tests. If you only have Premium or Professional you do not get access to that feature.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for that clarity. I only have Premium! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) since it is simple and powerful enough. However, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/06/04/getting-started-with-load-testing-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx) is a pretty detailed introduction to the VS 2012 load testing